# How to generate a route without specifying parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony, url-routing

I have a route :

```
 * @Route("/{id}/delete", name="details_delete")
 * @Method("post")
```

And I want to write :

```
$.ajax('{{ path('details_delete') }}',{
             data : form ,
             type: 'post',
```

is there a way without using `$this->getRequest();` ?

Comment: i couldn't see any place in which you are using `$this->getRequest()`. right?

Comment: yes, but I can change the route to `@Route("/delete", name="details_delete")` and then use `$this->getRequest()` in my controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
var url = '{{ path('details_delete', {'id': '__id__'}) }}';

$.ajax(url.replace('__id__', id),{
         data : form ,
         type: 'post',
```

Answer (score 0):

use a default key for id in the route

```
@Route("/{id}/delete", name="details_delete" defaults={"id"="default_id"})
@Method("post")
```

try like this

```
$.ajax('{{ path('details_delete', {'id': id}) }}',{
             type: 'post',
```

then you can access the id from the controller like this

```
public function idAction($id){
    //$id is the route parameter which you need
}
```

**EDIT**

Accessing javascript variable within twig block is not possible, because Javascript is rendered client-side at the browser, the Twig/PHP server side before being passed to the browser

The workaround is using [FOSJSRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle)

Hope this helps

Comment: but the **id** that I want to send, is a javascript variable not a twig variable

Comment: I know that I can't, that's why I asked this question, thanks!